# knockout template inside foreach inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, knockout.js

I am trying to apply a template to a foreach inside an iframe.

I made a quick example.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lyHeZNSlQVd098KycOsx?p=preview)

Main

```
<html>
    <body>
         <iframe src='iframe.html' width="300" height="300"></iframe>
     </body>
</html>
```

Script

```
 window.onload = function() {
     function MyViewModel() {
         this.people = [
             { name: 'Franklin', credits: 250 },
             { name: 'Mario', credits: 5800 }
         ]
         this.buyer = this.people[0]; 
     }

     DATA = new MyViewModel();  

     ko.applyBindings(DATA);
     ko.applyBindings(DATA, window.frames[0].document.body);
};
```

In the Iframe knockout can find the template for a simple binding but he can't with foreach

```
<!--this Work -->
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: buyer }"></div>


<!--this does not -->
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', foreach: people }"></div>



<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
</script>
```

knockout can make the binding if I add the template in the parent, but I'm looking for a way to leave my template in the other view

Comment: I think this might be relevant, looks like you need a custom template engine https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/405

Answer (score 0):

The link Will gives above does shed some insights. If you put your template in both the iframe.html and the index.html, it works:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pJ2QnjcEd6qCz72o10YT?p=preview

Now I've posted a plnkr link, StackOverflow wants me to give you some code, so here is your new index.html with the uncommented template you already had in there! All I've done is remove the comment tags so that the template is present in both HTML files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="knockout@*" data-semver="3.2.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>


    <script type="text/html" id="person-template">
        <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
        <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
    </script>

    <iframe src='iframe.html' width="300" height="300"></iframe>

  </body>

</html>
```

Although it seems like code duplication to have your template in both files, hopefully you can use a server-side mechanism like PHP require to include a single file in both places such that you're not duplicating code.